# Kibana extract number

Tags: kibana

I need to extract a number from a message in kibana and found all value that are greater than 1, is there a way to get that number not in yellow?, my logs are these:
[image: kibana logs]

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using regex:
message: "Time for external call to Firebase:" AND /[1-9].[0-9]{1,3}/